# Bibliography Autokey Generation in batch mode

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, cross-referencing, jabref

Is it possible to generate the bibtex keys for many bibliography entries at the same time or in a batch mode?

I am using Jabref for the bibliograpy database and get the bibtex key while inputting the data. The problem is that when I am taking the bibtex entries from other sources, there citation key format varies from source to source. Jabref reads the text file but the keys are very different or dont follow any pattern. It is best to have a consistent citation key format and it will be very helpful if there is a way to use the key format I am using on all the entries rather than generating the key for each entry individually.

Thanking in advance for any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a multiple select in jab-ref (either using ctrl-click or shift-click) and hit the magic wand button to generate keys for those selected entries.

Comment: I have already tried doing that. The key is generated only for the last entry of the selection.

Comment: well, then you only select that entry?

Comment: Thank you for the reply but it doesnt answer the question.

Comment: This actually works if the interface for inputting information is not open.

Answer (score 1):

You can autogenerate new BibTeX keys with Jabref (There is a menu under tools). After your imports, just regenerate the keys.